# Dictionary key error when parsing tweets with twitter api

Tags: python, api, dictionary, twitter, tweets

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import pw
import json


access_token = pw.access_token
access_token_secret = pw.access_token_secret
consumer_key = pw.consumer_key
consumer_secret = pw.consumer_secret


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        dicto = json.loads(data)
        print(dicto['user'])              
        return True


    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
stream.filter(track="music")
```

So I just followed a simple tutorial to process tweets. I'm just trying to parse the tweets, however when I use print(dicto['user']) it prints some and then throws a key error. The weird thing is that it's always after the 48th one. If I simply print the whole dictionary then it happily prints away. Right after the 48th piece of information is says traceback (most recent call last).

I'm a little confused what's going on here.

Comment: The `KeyError` means that key isn't in the dict. You can use `dicto.get('user')`, which returns `None` if the key is missing instead of raising `KeyError`. You can also give the `.get` method a default value to return instead of `None`.

Comment: ah awesome, I didn't know about get. I'm wondering can I specify a secondary key for get? So User is the key, but the value is another dictionary, and i'd like to get ['user']['location'] for example.

Comment: It seems that when mt .get returns my specified NaN value, the data contains {"limit":{"track":82,"timestamp_ms":"1529159543788"}}, so I'll take a look into what that is. Thanks for you suggestion, very helpful.

Comment: I'm stupid, I can just assign the get to a variable and access by the subkey like usual :)

Comment: No, you can't pass a secondary key to `get`. But you could do something like `d = dicto.get('user')` `if d: loc = d['location']`, assuming that if `dicto['user']` exists it always has a 'location' key.